# How can I get the nth-child of a Bootstrap .card body

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to set the background-color of card-body in bootstrap 4, however I'm not sure how I can obtain the card-body element as each body has a different parent (I think my understanding of this is correct), is it possible to do this using the below code?

I've put a sample snippet below which shows the paragraphs working, but the cards are not working here:

```css
.bg-alt:nth-child(5n+1){background-color: #5bc0de;}
.bg-alt:nth-child(5n+2){background-color: #ed9c28;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<p class="bg-alt"><span>test 1</span></p>
<p class="bg-alt"><span>test 1</span></p>
<p class="bg-alt"><span>test 1</span></p>
<p class="bg-alt"><span>test 1</span></p>

<div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 grid-margin ">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="bg-alt">
  98787667f
  </div>  
 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 grid-margin">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="bg-alt">
   45645656u57u5
  </div>  
 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 grid-margin">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="bg-alt">
   456456456456
  </div>  
 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 grid-margin">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="bg-alt">
   123123123
  </div>  
 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 grid-margin">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="bg-alt">
 123123
  </div>  
 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 grid-margin">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="bg-alt">
324234234
   </div>
  </div>  
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "card-body" is always the ONLY child (never the fifth), as the "nth-child" selector only references immediate siblings.
Try:

```css
.col-xl-2:nth-child(5n+1) .bg-alt {background-color: #5bc0de;}
.col-xl-2:nth-child(5n+2) .bg-alt {background-color: #ed9c28;}
```